# upload images to template directory

Tags: django

I have a model with this field:

```
image=models.ImageField(upload_to='company-category')
```

`company-category` is a folder in `uploads` folder,but I want to upload images to template directory .I think this way users that visit my website can't access images and download them.

in settings:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "C:/ghoghnous/HubHub/Theme"
)
```

how can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand how users can access files in your uploads folder? And who are the users? Explain little clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm giving two solutions. The one you asked and then my suggestion.

Use the following code to set the upload location to your templates folder.

```
from django.conf import settings

image=models.ImageField(upload_to = settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS[0])
```

The above code will upload image to your template directory.

**My Suggestion:**

Upload images to your media folder. Then use the `MEDIA_URL` to allow users to download them. Use the following code to define them.

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/ghoghnous/HubHub/media'
MEDIA_URL  = 'site_media'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
)
```

**models.py**

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images')
```

If you use this, the images will be uploaded to the folder `C:/ghoghnous/HubHub/media/images/`. Then get your required images by using `objects.get` or `objects.filter`.

```
record = SampleModel.objects.get(id = 1)
```

If I `print record.image`, the output will be `images/filename.jpg`.
Pass this to your template. Then you can display the image or give download link as follows:

```
<a href="{{ record.image.url }}/" >Download</a>        #Download link
<img src="{{ record.image.url }}/" />                  #To display image
<a href="/site_media/images/file.jpg" >Download</a>    #Download static files
```

I suggest you using the second method, since saving images in templates folder is not adviced.

Answer (score 0):

Template directory is not a preferred place to store media as per Django good practices.

Also, any images that you display on the web page will have a path and can be downloaded. Some people use scripting to stop right clicks and stuff like this but as far as I understand source code always give you image paths.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think you'd like to upload the file to a temporary folder and then do something with it. Right?

You need to override method `clean_image` in `forms`. Then you can write your own code with any path you want using [File storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#file-storage)